# Map DNS requests coming from specific client MAC with dnsmasq

Tags: networking, dns, openwrt, dnsmasq

I'm using [dnsmasq on OpenWRT](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/dhcp.dnsmasq).

Is it possible to map certain hostnames for DNS requests coming from a specific client? The ultimate goal in my case is to map certain hostnames to 127.0.0.1 to block them.

For example, the `/etc/hosts` file changes the mapping for all requests, but what if you only wanted client X to map a certain hostname?

I'm able to block certain IPs for a client MAC with firewall, but I want to block certain hostnames specifically.

Comment: Something like this: https://serverfault.com/questions/509388/per-client-dns-servers-with-dnsmasq?

Answer (score 1):

You could start up a second DNSMASQ with DNS only on a virtual machine or real interface, and assign the second DNSMASQ server from the first server

```
dhcp-host=00:51:99:72:8f:89,set:specialhosts,192.168.1.2
dhcp-option=tag:specialhosts,option:dns-server,192.168.1.2
```

And then on the second server you could add:

```
address=/baddomain.com/127.0.0.1
```

But the easiest way to do this if you have access to the host file on the client is to add the following to it:

```
127.0.0.1 baddomain.com
```